# Selecting from a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract returned array?

Tags: arrays, zend-framework

A simple select of this form:

```
            $select = $this->select();
            return $rowset = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

Now, There is an inherit column in the array, so the table is of the form:

```
   id   |   role   |   inherits   |
   1    |   admin  |    2         |
   2    |   player |    3         |
```

And When displayed I would like the inherirs column to show the Role it actually inherits from instead of the id.

The array returned by Zend_Db_Table_Abstract is extremely convoluted, so I can't just say:

```
$array[0][inherits]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $this->fetchAll will not return array it is going to return `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract` object. You can learn more about it here in [Zend_Db_Table_Rowset Zend Docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html).

You can get data from it as an object

```
// use Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract object
$array[0]->inherits
```

Or if you want to get an array you can do this:

```
// get rowset and convert it to array
$rowset = $this->fetchAll($select);
$data = ($rowset) ? $rowset->toArray() : array();
```

---

Better solution would be to write a left join on the same table and get the role in the dataset without any PHP code.

```
$sql = $this->getAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('r1' => 'your_roles_table'), '*')
        ->joinLeft(array('r2' => 'your_roles_table'), 'r2.id = r1.inherits', array(
            'inherits_role' => 'r2.role',
        ));

$data = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($sql);
var_dump($data);
```